# Confusing simple python list behavior with +=

Tags: python

```
list4=[7,8]
def proc3(mylist):
    mylist+=[9]


print list4
proc3(list4)
print list4
```

Why does this code produce the answers [7,8] and [7,8,9]? I expected [7,8] and [7,8].
Doesn't mylist+=[9] concatenate the number 9 and create a new list as a local variable only? Why does the "print list4" after the running proc3(list4), but outside the procedure, not result in the original list? I must be missing something obvious here. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Even though you are correct that `proc3` has a different reference to the `list` object than the one in your global namespace, the `+=` operator *mutates* the list. You're altering the object itself, it doesn't matter that you're doing it with a second reference.

Comment: Check this answer which explains everything you need to know for pass by value and pass by reference in python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+=` does *not* return a new list object.  Instead, it modifies the original list object in-place.

In other words, this line inside `proc3`:

```
mylist+=[9]
```

is modifying the list object referenced by `mylist`.  As a result, it is no longer `[7, 8]` but `[7, 8, 9]`.

Comment: So does the += operator act similarly to mylist.append(9) which mutates the list? I thought it was the same as mylist=mylist+[9], which points to a new concatenated list...

Comment: One more thing. It's not exactly the same as .append, because mylist.append([9,10]) creates [7,8,[9,10]], whereas mylist+=[9,10] creates [7,8,9,10], right? Thanks for the help, this is quite subtle for such a simple operation :-).

Comment: @iCodez Actually, `+=` works exactly like `mylist.extend`.  If it were like `mylist.append` then `mylist += [9]` would result in `[7, 8, [9]]`.  It's an important distinction, especially if someone were to do something like `mylist += 'hello'` and would get the unexpected result of `[7, 8, 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`

Comment: @user3150100 Ha, yes, I should have read your comment first.  `+=` is a shortcut for `list.extend`.

Comment: @SethMMorton - Yes, my mistake (I'll remove my previous comment so that there is no future confusion :).  When the OP said `list.append`, I focused on it being an in-place operation like `+=`.  But `list.extend` is a lot more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2322079/2670792) in another post:

> Everything is a reference in Python. If you wish to avoid that behavior you would have to create a new copy of the original with `list()`. If the list contains more references, you'd need to use `deepcopy()`:

Let's:

```
list4 = [7, 8]
def proc3(mylist):
    print id(list4)
    mylist += [9]
    print id(list4)


print list4
print id(list4)
proc3(list4)
print id(list4)
print list4
```

This would print:

```
[7, 8]
36533384
36533384
36533384
36533384
[7, 8, 9]
```

So as you can see, it's the same list in every moment.

Answer (score 0):

the `+=` operator modifies the object. Notice that

```
x += y
```

is much different from

```
x = x + y
```

(check with your test code)