# Modify a int list in function in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to rotate k element in a list in python. For example, n = 7, k = 3, and the array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] is rotated to [5,6,7,1,2,3,4].

Here is the statement I wrote. It seems to work in the command line.

```
nums = nums[k%len(nums):] + nums[:k%len(nums)]
```

But when I encapsulate it in a function like:

```
def rotate(nums, k):
    nums = nums[k%len(nums):] + nums[:k%len(nums)]
    return
```

I want to modify nums directly, but this function doesn't work.

I know that I can use a for loop like:

```
for i in range(k):
    nums.insert(0,nums.pop())
```

but I want to know why the previous method doesn't work?

Comment: You create a new list inside the function then don't return or assign anything as a result; why did you expect that to make changes outside the function?

Comment: `nums=...` sets the local variable `nums`, but does not change the actual original list `nums`. for the inverse problem see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322068/python-passing-list-as-argument

Comment: Side-note: Even fixed with slice assignment, this is incredibly inefficient if the `list` is of significant size (you make a complete copy of the `list`, then copy back into the original `list`); if rotating sequences is important in your use case, consider [using `collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) which can perform rotation much more efficiently, with direct support for [in-place rotation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate).

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a slice assignment:

```
nums[:] = nums[k%len(nums):] + nums[:k%len(nums)]
```

This mutates the list that was passed in, so the change is visible after the function returns.  Assigning just to `nums` merely makes `nums` point to a different list inside the function; it doesn't affect the original list.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to modify nums?  You need not create a separate list even if you do not modify nums.  One advantage of the following approach is that it will work with any sequence.

```
from itertools import islice
def rotate(lst, k):
    n = len(lst)
    start = n - (k % n)  #handle all ints
    for item in islice(lst, start, None):
        yield item
    for item in islice(lst, 0, start):
        yield item
```

If you insist on modifying nums as you say, you can still do so.  E.g.,

```
nums = [x + 1 for x in range(7)]
nums[:] = rotate(nums,-10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `nums` that is inside the function is only within that function. So you need to return it from that function. One way is like this (python 2.7 code, add parentheses to `print` if you use 3.x):

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
k = 3


def rotate(nums, k):
    return nums[k%len(nums):] + nums[:k%len(nums)]

print 'Original', nums
nums = rotate(nums, k)
print 'Rotated', nums
```